# Apache Kafka consumer takes long time when used as a plugin in pentaho

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, pentaho, vertica

[Consumer-transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMXrn.png)  [Producer-transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXFEq.png)

**OBJECTIVE :**
Transfer tables(120 tables) from oracle database to vertica database.

**Current practice:**
Use pentaho tool to extract data from oracle database and store it as a file and load them again into vertica database.

**Problem faced :**
The entire process running for a long time.
Storing it as file occupies more space and reduces performance.

**New approach:**
Use Kafka as a messaging system and its plugin in pentaho.

**Problem faced:**
Consumer plugin takes huge amount of time for consuming message and loading into vertica tables.(6 times the time taken for loading message into producer).
1. Avro format
2. Sample of 2 million records with 200 columns

We would like to hear suggestions to improve this performance or suggest any other way to meet the objective using Kafka.

Comment: Are you using Pentaho 7 ?

Comment: Yes , I am using pentaho 7.1

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://my.vertica.com/kb/HPE-Vertica-Integration-with-Pentaho-Data-Integration-PDI-Tips/Content/BestPractices/HPE-Vertica-Integration-with-Pentaho-Data-Integration-PDI-Tips.htm) suggest to use the `Vertica Bulk Loader` step directly after the Oracle `Table input`.

Comment: I need to add few columns and make some changes to my source data before loading into Vertica so i cannot add Vertica Bulk Loader step immediately after Table input.

Comment: But tried Vertica Bulk Loader after all my changes and additions of column , still the performance is almost same. Please refer the screen shot for details